# Why is the Access Key E&xit not working in my VB program

Tags: vb.net, access-keys

I'm writing a VB program where I want to be able to "push" an Exit button with a keyboard shortcut to close the program.  I understand that if I put an & in the text of the button (E&xit), I can create a Alt-X shortcut to exit.

I've written programs where it's worked before; it's simple, but now it's not working. In fact, it's not even underlining the x in the text on the button. It's like a setting is telling it to be ignored.  (I'm using the latest version of MS Visual Studio.)

I have found that if I turn on the form setting KeyPreview=True, it will work, but the x is still not underlined, so there is no visual indication of the shortcut being available. I feel like I'm missing some setting or switch that make this activate normally.  Can someone explain or point me in the right direction?  Thanks.

Comment: If you create a new project and try what you described without making any other changes, does it work?

Comment: Whether or not the underline is visible is a setting in Windows and not your program.  Go into System Settings > Ease of Access > Keyboard and check the setting named "Underline access keys when available".  It may be switched off.

Comment: Chris, thanks.  The way I just had it working, I see the underline when looking at the form in visual studio.  When I run it, I do not see the underline, until I press the alt key for the first time, then it remains visible after that. I checked the setting you suggested and it was off, so I turned it on.  Now when I run it, it's immediately underlined.  That's more like I expected it, so I'll leave that on. I'm still unsure exactly what was happening the other night, but I've learned a few things anyhow.

Answer (score -1):

jmcilhinney,  well, now it's working, both on new and existing apps, even with keypreview turned off.  I think there was something strange going on with Visual Studio that day.  Other parts of my program (with KeyPress handling) were not working correctly either at that time.  Then suddenly everything started to behave as expected.  Or maybe it was something I was doing with Keypress that messed up the Access Keys.  I wish I could explain better, but now I can't reproduce the problem.